# Mercurial: create new user incl. password

Tags: mercurial

I have a new private repository and I'd like to add users to push/pull. 
So, my question is: How can I create new users, incl. a password?
After that, I know that I have to add them to the hgrc-file.

Thanks a lot for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how did you configured to host your repo. The easy solution is to use *hg* through *ssh*, but you can follow different aproaches as well (e.g., we're using *SCM* with *LDAP*). Unfortunately, I don't think there's an easy way to do that with `hg serve`...

You can also try any public hosting companies like [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org), probably that's the easiest way.

Comment: We use hg through ssh, and I have admin-rights. My question is really which hg-commands I have to use in order to create a new user... Thanks for any help.

Comment: Nope, you cannot do that. You have to channel through hg over something that manages authing (ssh/any httpd). So if you're using SSH, you must add the users to the system, that's all. You gain more sophisticated control over access with Apache/LightHTTPD/whatever. You'll find [Chapter 6.](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/collaborating-with-other-people.html) of the Hg Definitive Guide Book handy.

Comment: But we use a "hgusers"-file, where all the users (incl. encrypted passwort) is saved. There isn't any possibility to create a new user through hg add user (or something like that)?

Comment: I'm not aware of any "hgusers" file you may use (if it is not an extension). Isn't that file an `AuthUserFile` set in your Apache config? That way you simply use `htpasswd /path/to/hgusers newuser`. Hg itself does not handle authing (neither the others like SVN/Git/etc).